# This Question Appears to be Defamation

Tags: discussion, questions

[This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/97795/when-a-professor-commits-scientific-fraud-are-the-journal-reviewers-and-editors) purports that the linked article demonstrates that a person the OP mentions by name committed fraud. This is not true, as both commenters and the answer have noted. However, I worry that the post itself is defamation.

The core question (“what happens to the journal’s reputation when it publishes fraud”) can be asked without the example, or with an example of someone who is widely known as having committed fraud and who has had their paper retracted on those grounds (for example, Andrew Wakefield).

What do people think the correct course of action is? Should the question be edited? Deleted? Something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the question itself is salvageable - and indeed, I think the spurious accusation can be dealt with in a sentence or two (as my answer did).

Since then, the question has been edited, and now I think is a fully formed, acceptable and on-topic question for the site.